# Parsing PHP using attribute value in node instead of order of node

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

Example of XML

```
<book name="Queen" id="xxxx0">
<descriptions>
<description synopsis="bla bla bla"/>
</descriptions>
</book>


<book name="King" id="xxxx7">
<descriptions>
<description synopsis="snu snu snu"/>
</descriptions>
</book>
```

and so on...

Right now, I can parse using simplexml_load_file like this:

```
echo $xml->book[0]['name']."<br>";

echo $xml->book[1]['name']."<br>";
```

How do I parse using the id value instead of the order of the attribute book?

Comment: I would have to look it up in [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php), so why dont you,  Thanks that will save me bothering my little head with all that reading

Comment: I can't understand what you want. If you want to get `id` attribute use `xml->book[0]['id'].`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath will let you choose nodes any way you want.

```
$king = $xml->xpath('//book[@id="xxxx7"]');
```